# Using shiny and DT datatables in shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to use in a shiny app both datatables of library shiny and DT.

When running locally in Rstudio, everything works fine, when running on the server I can't have all functionalities working. Let me show my example:

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
require(rCharts)    

# Define a server for the Shiny app
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  output$table1<-renderDataTable({
    a<-data.table(seq(1,50),seq(1,50),rep("fsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf",50))
  } , options = list(orderClasses = TRUE,pageLength=10,lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 25,50),filter = "top"), escape = FALSE)


  output$table2<-renderDataTable({

  a<-as.data.table(data.table(seq(1,50),seq(1,50),rep("asfafasfafafaffsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf",50)))

 }, options = list( processing=FALSE, columnDefs = list(list(
  targets =   3,
  render = JS(
    "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
    "return type === 'display' && data.length > 5 ?",
    "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 5)+ '...</span>': data;",
    "}")
)
),orderClasses = TRUE,pageLength=10,lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 25,50),filter = "top"), escape = FALSE)



  output$table3<- shiny::renderDataTable({
    a<-data.table(seq(1,50),seq(1,50),rep("fsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf",50))

    addCheckboxButtons <- paste0('<input type="checkbox" name="row_bb', a$V1, '" value="', a$V1, '">',"")
    aa<-cbind(Pick=addCheckboxButtons, a)

    return(aa)

  } ,options = list(orderClasses = TRUE, lengthMenu = c(5, 25, 50), pageLength = 25)
  , callback = JS("function(table) {
                  table.on('change.dt', 'tr td input:checkbox', function() {
                  setTimeout(function () {
                  Shiny.onInputChange('row_bb', $(this).add('tr td input:checkbox:checked').parent().siblings(':last-child').map(function() {
                  return $(this).text();
                  }).get())
                  }, 10);
                  });
}"),escape = FALSE

  )


})
```

and ui.R

```
 require(rCharts) 
 require(shiny) 
 require(shinydashboard)
 library(shinydashboard) 
 library(shinythemes) 
 library(shinyjs)
 library(shinyBS) 
 library(DT)



 dbHeader<-dashboardHeader()

 dashboardPage(skin = "black",
               dbHeader,
               dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
                 id = "sidebarmenu",
                 menuItem('tab', tabName = 'dashboard', icon = icon('dashboard'))
               )),


          dashboardBody(tabItems(
            tabItem(
              tabName = "dashboard",
              dataTableOutput("table1"),
              dataTableOutput("table2"),
              shiny::dataTableOutput("table3")                 

            ))))
```

and global.R is loading shiny and DT libraries.

What's is happening is that table1 is frozen and saying "Processing...", table 2 is not changing pages and only table 3 is working properly.

when changing both server and ui to

```
shiny::dataTableOutput("table1"),
DT::dataTableOutput("table2"),
shiny::dataTableOutput("table3")
```

only table 2 is not working properly.

Can someone help in this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: The requires and librarys in your ui.R are all on one line and this will not work in R. I suspect this is not the source of your problem but you should make sure your code pasted here is exactly the code you are running. Please edit or otherwise fix it.

Comment: In your example where only table 3 works, you are using `shiny::dataTableOutput` for table 3. In your example where table 1 and 3 works, you are using `shiny::dataTableOutput` for tables 1 and 3. Can't say for sure but try using `shiny::dataTableOutput` for all three.

Comment: @JulianZucker The checkbox option is a functionality of shiny package, reason why I use "shiny::". In table 2, the functionality of reducing text is from library DT, but when I use DT:: it doesn't solve the problem